# Creating a linked list from a text file

Tags: c, algorithm, text, linked-list

I'm teaching myself about linked lists and have proposed a basic problem to solve. I want to line by line read a text file that will have names and add each name to my linked list.

An example of the text file would be:

```
John
Jacob
Jingleheimer
Smith
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to dynamically add to my proposed linked list. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void)
{
    struct node {
        char *name;
        struct node* next;
    };


    static const char* fileName = "test.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    struct node* head = NULL; // first node

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {
        //add line of text to linked list
    }
    if (line)
        free(line);

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Any pointers into the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, to do this you need to first allocate a node entry, then copy the line you just read into it. Then add it to the list. (I've left out error handling, such as malloc returning NULL).

```
/* This will store the last read line first */
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    n->name = strdup(line); /* copy the line since it can get reused by getline */
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
}
```

Comment: I need help with the list insert part.

Comment: Is this compatible with my existing linked list structure? I am getting errors

Comment: You probably need to add #include <string.h> but other than that it works for me with no warnings or errors.

Comment: I got it working. Do you have any tips for linked where items will have "child" nodes and I will have to link those as well

Comment: you mean how to splice two lists together? Search for the end of one of the lists, and add the other there.  Something like this (the semi colons are important!): for(n = head2; n->next != NULL; n=n->next);  n->next = head;  head = head2;

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory to hold the string, set that memory = to the string.
Then

```
node *next = malloc(sizeof(node));
next->name = name;
next->next = NULL;
head->next = next;
head = next;
```

Comment: So I put that into my loop and that is all?

Comment: No problem, but the code will segfault too. head is NULL the first time through the loop.

Comment: I'm assuming he realizes that and will make it not NULL before entering the loop.

Comment: If you're assuming it, you should say so, because the OP won't assume what you're assuming.  Unstated assumptions wreck many projects; ask the people at NASA who crashed the [Mars Climate Orbiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter) because they didn't check the units, or the people in the ESA who crashed an [Ariane 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501) rocket after take-off because the code needed before take-off ran into problems with overflows after take-off.